# Golang monorepo with multiple modules, unknown revision on import

Tags: go, versioning, monorepo

I have created a go repository, link: https://github.com/gardusig/grpc_service

Basically there's a `client` and `server`, each with its own module. Both of them consumes another module called `generated`, which also contains its own module.

Issue: failed to import through release tag, like `v1.0.0`. Works well through `commit hash` indeed.

I could have created a separate repo for each, but the goal is to see how far it's possible to reach with a monorepo. Simple example tree structure:

```
repo/
-- client/
---- go.mod
-- server/
---- go.mod
-- generated/
---- go.mod
```

Since it was pushed to `main` and released as let's say `v1.0.0`. The goal would be for both client and server `go.mod` to be able to do this:

```
require github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated v1.0.0
```

But it's not working. Long short story - release not found. When I do it through a commit hash it works. Example:

```
require github.com/gardusig/grpc_service v0.0.0-20230911193540-4b0bb3ff6475
```

Detailed error:

```
go: downloading github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated v1.0.7
go: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/server/internal imports
    github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated: reading github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated/go.mod at revision generated/v1.0.7: unknown revision generated/v1.0.7
go: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/server/internal imports
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus tested by
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus.test imports
    github.com/stretchr/testify/assert: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated@v1.0.7: reading github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated/go.mod at revision generated/v1.0.7: unknown revision generated/v1.0.7
go: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/server/internal imports
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus tested by
    github.com/sirupsen/logrus.test imports
    github.com/stretchr/testify/require: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated@v1.0.7: reading github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated/go.mod at revision generated/v1.0.7: unknown revision generated/v1.0.7
go: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/server/main imports
    google.golang.org/grpc tested by
    google.golang.org/grpc.test imports
    github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated@v1.0.7: reading github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated/go.mod at revision generated/v1.0.7: unknown revision generated/v1.0.7
go: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/server/main imports
    google.golang.org/grpc imports
    google.golang.org/grpc/internal/balancer/gracefulswitch tested by
    google.golang.org/grpc/internal/balancer/gracefulswitch.test imports
    github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts: github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated@v1.0.7: reading github.com/gardusig/grpc_service/generated/go.mod at revision generated/v1.0.7: unknown revision generated/v1.0.7
```

I feel that I'm missing something about the way go project structure should look like. Any advice?

Looks like this works but not as expected:

```
require github.com/gardusig/grpc_service v1.0.0
```

Reason: when running `go mod tidy` it goes back to import `generated` module through a commit hash again.

Comment: What if you run that module-fetching commands while having `GIT_TRACE=1` in environment? Also add "be verbose" option to that `go` invocation (it's either `-v` or `-x`, if supported). The point of interest is whether the tooling fails to locate the relevant VCS tag.